# Sort and Delete duplicate image files

Tags: c#, time-limit-exceeded, image

I'm trying to make a console application to sort and delete duplicate image files. I have a folder with about 20000 images which take up roughly 70GB of space.

I wrote the following script and it seems to work fine, but the issue is that my PC runs out of available RAM memory (it has 16GB) without reaching halfway through.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var uniqueData = new HashSet<string>();
    
    int progress = 0;
    int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(imageFolderPath).Length;

    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(imageFolderPath))
    {
        string data, year, month;

        using (var image = Image.FromFile(file))
        {

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                data = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }

            try //try to get image date
            {
                var date = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(image.GetPropertyItem(36867).Value).Split(':');
                year = date[0];
                month = date[1];
            }
            catch
            {
                year = "Unknown";
                month = "Unknown";
            }
        }

        if (!uniqueData.Contains(data))
        {
            uniqueData.Add(data);

            string yearDirectory = Path.Combine(outputFolderPath, year);
                
            if (!Directory.Exists(yearDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(yearDirectory);
            }

            string monthDirectory = Path.Combine(yearDirectory, (int.TryParse(month, out int i) && i > 0 && i < 14) ? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i) : month);

            if (!Directory.Exists(monthDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(monthDirectory);
            }

            File.Move(file, Path.Combine(monthDirectory, Path.GetFileName(file)));
        }
        else
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }

        progress++;
        Console.WriteLine($"{progress} / {fileCount}");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this code doing?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/259022/2) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: @aepot it extracts the bytes of each image file in the designated folder, and converts them to a string. Then it checks if the string is already present in a hashset, and if it is, it deletes said file, otherwise, it tries to create a folder based on the file's date and moves it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to store the whole file contents, compute hash instead. Also converting each image to JPEG is not necessary, use `image.RawFormat`, it would be a bit faster.

```
using (SHA256 sha = SHA256.Create())
using (var ms = new MemoryStream((int)new FileInfo(file).Length))
{
    image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
    ms.Position = 0;
    data = Convert.ToBase64String(sha.ComputeHash(ms));
}
```

2nd option

```cs
if (!uniqueData.Contains(data))
{
    uniqueData.Add(data);
    // ...
}
```

Can be simplified to

```cs
if (uniqueData.Add(data))
{
    // ...
}
```

Also twice getting the directoriry files can be once

```cs
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(imageFolderPath);
int fileCount = files.Length;

foreach (var file in files)
{
    // ...
}
```

And finally this one

```cs
if (!Directory.Exists(yearDirectory))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(yearDirectory);
}
```

`Directory.CreateDirectory` creates directory if it not exists, otherwise it does nothing. You can remove `Exists` check.

```cs
Directory.CreateDirectory(yearDirectory);
```

Comment: Excellent, so far it has not exceeded 200MB of memory (it's still going but it looks very promising), I will try to benchmark the impact of each of your suggested changes and append it to my question as edit. Cheers!

Comment: @oRoiDev you're welcome. Btw, don't edit the question. Some users here suggests to post the final code as additional answer if you want but it isn't necessary.

Comment: @oRoiDev one more improvement and fixed a bug, updated the answer.